# Why am I getting "Host '192.168.1.220' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to run MySQL (phpMyAdmin) on a LAN. This is my connection string:

```
Function Connection() As MySqlConnection
    'Connect Database
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.101;" _
 & "user id=root;" _
 & "password=;" _
 & "database=db1230018;"
    '
    MyConnection.Open()
    Return MyConnection
End Function
```

I get an error:

> Host '192.168.1.220' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

I have two PCs. One of them (Windows 7 - 192.168.1.101) runs a WAMP server (phpMyAdmin) and a VB.NET application using the above connection string. Now I want to run the application on the second pc (Windows) using the same database in 192.168.1.101. I already define a fixed IP on both PCs and disable firewalls. What's going on?

Answer (score 15):

Probably you have no access rule defined for `root@192.168.1.220`. Then the server refuses this connection.

Besides, you have to remove the restriction about the bind address in the config file.

[Here](http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/) you are told how that works:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

in MySQL and remove the line

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

As you get the said message from the server, it might be that the latter step isn't necessary any longer. Otherwise, you would get a message from the client that it is unable to connect to the server.

Comment: sry 4 asking pls explain of password

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

i think you haven't given sufficient privileges to the specified `'root'@'host'`

you should look into the `user.mysql` table and give sufficient privileges to that particular `'user'@'host'`.